# RDLC Design Group Horizontally

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

Forgive me for the title as I don't know how to put this in words.

Expected Output:

```
  #  |  X  |  Y  |  #  |  X  |  Y  
  1  |A1   |A2   |  26 |B1   |B2
  2                 27
  3                 28
  .                  .
  .                  .
  .                  .
  25 |D1   |D2   |  50 |E1   |E2
```

I want to limit the row count to 25 and I want to continue horizontally.

The main reason why the format of the report I want to make is like this is to consume the entire page. The columns `# X Y` would only have a width of 4 inches in total, thus we expect that rows 51-100 will be on the 2nd page of the report.

Is this possible? I am familiar with paging in RDLC through the use of groups but the rows would repeat vertically downwards which is not what I'm looking for.

I can group my data from 1 to 25 as Group 1 and 26 to 50 as Group 2 and so on, but I don't know how to display the group horizontally.

I am open to new designs as long as the page will filled with data.

P.S. We're not a fan of putting papers to waste.

Comment: Do you have a SQL based Dataset?  If so, could you add the code to your answer?

Comment: @iamdave yes, we are using an SQL based dataset mainly oracle but grouping the data in terms of 25 is not my problem. I can do that but I am having difficulty displaying the data as per my requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been decided that we would give up on this design. I am now using a simple table without grouping to display the data. Columns were expanded from a total of 4in to 8in so that there will be less unused space in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, you are looking to create a grouping in your SQL dataset every 25 rows, which you can then create a column grouping on in your report.

SQL Example that groups every 25 records (no access to SQL Server at the moment so the code isn't tested but you can see the idea):

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() as RowNum,
    tbl.#, tbl.X, tbl.Y
  FROM tbl
)
SELECT 
    (T.RowNum) / 25 as GroupID,
    T.X, 
    T.Y
FROM T
GROUP BY ((T.RowNum) / 25)
```

Once your dataset has this new "GroupID", create a column grouping on this field and that should create the additional columns to fill the page up.

Comment: Thanks but I'm having a hard time displaying the data in my required format. I can group the data by 25 as I am well familiar with paging in RDLC.